# case class modification and design generic way

Tags: scala, shapeless

code snippets are trivialized, sampled, for the purpose of this post.

```
case class Person(firstName:String,lstName:String)
```

This person class has been used all over the place in a codebase. Now later requirements changed and deciding to add `phoneNumber` in the person case class

e.g.

```
case class Person(firstName:String,lstName:String,phoneNumber:String)
```

again, examples are extremely simplified in the post. In reality there are more interesting things are happening. Note that `phoneNumber` is not an `Option` but a required field. Generally one would go and update all the code that's using `Person` class, to cater new field `lastName`. which is quite tedious when you have 100 references of it.

Can shapeless help in creating more flexible `HList` from get go vs case class?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to go about it would be to provide a default value for `phoneNumber`:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, phoneNumber: String = "")
```

Alternatively, you could create a companion object and implement an `apply()` method for both cases, i.e. with and without `phoneNumber`. If you decide to take this approach, and you're using the case class in pattern matches, you might also want to implement the corresponding `unapply()` methods.

Comment: You might also need to create `unapply()` methods if you don't want to break pattern matches